# Spinner receiving data in parentheses

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: Data loaded in spinner]

[image: Firebase database]

```
spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.department_spinner);

departmentDatabaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Departments");




departmentSpinnerDataList = new ArrayList<>();
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(createNewEmployeeTab.this, departmentSpinnerDataList);
spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
retrieveDepartmentData();

public void retrieveDepartmentData(){

        listener = departmentDatabaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                for (DataSnapshot item:dataSnapshot.getChildren()){


                    departmentSpinnerDataList.add(item.getValue().toString());

                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
```

This is the first time dealing with the database.I cant seem to find out where the issue is.I can't restructure the database as it is used in other screens aswell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
departmentSpinnerDataList.add(item.getValue().toString());
```

into this:

```
departmentSpinnerDataList.add(item.child("name").getValue().toString());
```

add the `child("name")` to retrieve the name attribute from the database.

Comment: Solved, Thank you

Comment: For type-safety I'd always recommend using `item.child("name").getValue(String.class)`.